# What is the difference between the two ways to invoke the method?

Tags: c#, delegates

In the method below what is the difference between using

`ListThreads.Add(new Task(() => item.Execute()));`

and

`ListThreads.Add(new Task(item.Execute));`

```
private void Execute()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ThreadNumber; i++)
    {
        ListObjects.Add(new MyClass(i + 1, ThreadNumber));
    }
    foreach (MyClass item in ListObjects)
    {
        ListThreads.Add(new Task(() => item.Execute()));
        ListThreads[ListThreads.Count - 1].Start();
    }
    Task.WaitAll(ListThreads.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Nothing is different between, (new Task(() => item.Execute()) and new Task(item.Execute). its just the first one is you explicitly writing the call as a Lamda where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask the difference between

```
() => item.Execute()
```

and

```
item.Execute
```

The former is a lambda that calls `item.Execute`. The, `item.Execute`, is a method group. When they are passed to the constructor of `Task` they are both converted to a delegate of type `Action`.

There is quite a difference though. The lambda captures the variable `item`. And the method group does not. This means that when the lambda is executed, the value of the variable `item` may be different from its value when you passed the lambda to the constructor of `Task`.

To make the lambda version equivalent to the method group version you could introduce a local variable:

```
foreach (MyClass item in ListObjects)
{
    MyClass tmpItem = item;
    ListThreads.Add(new Task(() => tmpItem.Execute()));
    ListThreads[ListThreads.Count - 1].Start();
}
```

Do note that the language has been modified between C# 4.0 and C# 5.0. In C# 5.0 the code in your question behaves in exactly the same way as does the code above in this answer. For more details see:

- [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful, part one](http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/)
- [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful, part two](http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-two/)
- [Has foreach's use of variables been changed in C# 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112881/has-foreachs-use-of-variables-been-changed-in-c-sharp-5)
- [Is "Access to modified closure" resolved by comprehension syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649337/is-access-to-modified-closure-resolved-by-comprehension-syntax/8649429#8649429)

Answer (score -2):

First of, it's a bad idea to use foreach variable in lambda expression. So, in this particular case the correct way is to write `ListThreads.Add(new Task(item.Execute));`

Comment: They do the exact same thing.. and the issue related to using a foreach variable in a lambda expression has been addressed by the C# 5 (?) compiler.

Comment: This is a poor answer due to not actually explaining what's going on.  It's also not correct to globally say that lambdas should not be used in `foreach` methods.  It's important to realize that lambdas close over *variables* not over *values*, but that doesn't mean you never do it, just that you're careful.  You are correct that in C# 4.0 the given code wouldn't reliably function properly, although dcastro is right that in C# 5.0 it would.  However in 4.0 a simple local variable copy of the loop variable is a sufficient fix.  If you *explained* what's going on, this could be a good answer.