# C# object property not accessible in Enumerable.Where within a foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

Found a c# head-scratcher. In the foreach loop, using the parent.Id property directly in a Enumerable.Where does not work. Putting it in a variable first works. There is no issue with directly accessing parent.Id in the Select statement.

```
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>() { 
        new Person() { Id = 1, name = "John", parentId = null },
        new Person() { Id = 2, name = "Sarah", parentId = null },
        new Person() { Id = 3, name = "Daniel", parentId = 1 },
        new Person() { Id = 4, name = "Peter", parentId = 1 }
    };

    List<object> peopleTree = new List<object>();

    var parents = people.Where(p => !p.parentId.HasValue);
    foreach (Person parent in parents)
    {
        int parentId = parent.Id;
        var children = people
            //.Where(p => p.parentId.Equals(parentId)) //This works, is able to find the children
            .Where(p => p.parentId.Equals(parent.Id)) //This does not work, no children for John
            .Select(p => new { Id = p.Id, Name = p.name, pId = parent.Id }); //pId set correctly

        peopleTree.Add(new
        {
            Id = parent.Id,
            Name = parent.name,
            Children = children
        });
    }
```

Alternatively, if I use a for loop and put parent in a variable first, I can access the parent.Id property directly in the Where statement.

```
var parents = people.Where(p => !p.parentId.HasValue).ToArray();
for (int idx = 0; idx < parents.Count(); idx++)
{
    var parent = parents[idx];
...
```

I could not find an answer to why it behaves like this.
Can anyone explain it?

Comment: In the second example you're calling 'ToArray'. This would probably also make your first example work.

Comment: Which version of framework are you using? May be I am not getting your question since it works fine for me.

Comment: @danish The framework version is irrelevant; the compiler version *is* relevant.  The behavior was changed in C# 5.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is created by the deferred execution of the `children`. Essentially, the value of `parent` at the time when `children` is evaluated is different. Geekspeak for this is [*Accessing Modified Closure*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/235455/335858).

You can fix it by introducing a temporary the way you did, or by forcing evaluation to happen while the `foreach` loop is still in the current iteration:

```
var children = people
    .Where(p => p.parentId.Equals(parent.Id))
    .Select(p => new { Id = p.Id, Name = p.name, pId = parent.Id })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Or just compile the code using the C# 5.0 compiler, rather than an earlier one.

Comment: @Servy That too :) I think Eric Lippert explained the rationale for this change in his blog, but I cannot find the post.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649337/is-access-to-modified-closure-resolved-by-comprehension-syntax/8649429#8649429 It's also linked from my answer

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the lazy nature of linq queries.  Linq queries will "materialize" as late as possible to avoid doing potentially unnecessary work.

`children` is a non-materialized `IEnumerable<T>`.  It won't be actually filled with elements.  There is a significant difference between `parent` and `parentId`, used in your two `.Where()` calls.  `parent` is only declared once, but `parentId` is scoped inside the loop, so effectively is declared multiple times.  At the time `children` is eventually materialized `parent` has changed values.  It will refer to the last element in `parents`, which is not what you intended.

You can force eager evaluation like this.

```
    var children = people
        .Where(p => p.parentId.Equals(parent.Id)) 
        .Select(p => new { Id = p.Id, Name = p.name, pId = parent.Id })
        .ToArray();  <---- this forces materialization
```

Comment: It isn't quite right to say that an IEnumerable itself is **ever** "materialized" with elements. Lists or arrays may be, but you can also have iterator block enumerable that never handle more than one item at a time, and the objects returned by the Select()/Where()/etc extension methods are actually state machines that operate on the original collection... they are never by themselves materialzed, even if you use them in a `foreach`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: You're right.  I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the statement that begins like this:

```
var children = people ...
```

This statement does not result it in a collection that actually stores values... it results in an IEnumerable object that knows how to iterate over a collection. The instructions used by this object happen to reference the `parent` variable from the loop. That variable is captured for the Enumerable into something called a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649337/is-access-to-modified-closure-resolved-by-comprehension-syntax/8649429#8649429). Later on, when you actually use the Enumerable object to access items, it looks back at that `parent` variable.

Here's the trick: there is *one* `parent` variable that mutates for each iteration through the original loop. At the end of the loop, all of the items in your `parents` collection are using the same `parent` object. Copying the `parent.Id` *value* to a variable inside the loop fixes the problem because you're now dealing with a new variable for the closure with each iteration through the loop.

You can also fix this by using a `.ToList()` call at the end of the statement indicated earlier to evaluate the Enumerable object while still inside the loop. However, I prefer your existing solution, because it's more memory efficient if you never need to expand all of those Children at the same time.

The good news is that [this problem is fixed for C# 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649337/is-access-to-modified-closure-resolved-by-comprehension-syntax/8649429#8649429).